# Have we done the [walkthrough]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/walkthrough) has around 60 questions at present.

Here's the [walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/walkthrough):

1. Does it describe the contents, is it unambiguous?

   It's hardly related to any content possibly asked in the question, and no, a walkthrough can be anything (though more commonly related to a "guidance" or "tutorial").
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   No. A walkthrough is just off-topic on its own.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   It does not.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   [Asking for code explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72577196/5958455), [Software reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71904829/5958455), [New user onboarding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72387318/5958455), [WalkthroughView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50856822/5958455), [Walkthrough (for code) for an exam](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10181149/5958455) and [Walking through code in debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14651073/5958455) could be the same thing... or is it? (*NO PLEASE NOOOO!!!*)

So if we've gone through the [walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/walkthrough), we no longer need it, right?

Comment: Note: retag questions that are about the class [tag:bwwalkthrough] to use that tag ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30218723/6083675)). I'm not sure that any are left after I tried to get them all properly tagged a while ago however.

Comment: @Laurel That tag has no usage guidance yet.

Comment: @Mast That doesn't make the tag useless. See the example question I linked for context about what the tag is about. I can try my hand at writing guidance, though I have no idea about any of the technologies involved.

Comment: This tag sounds very useful... for helping identify questions that should be closed and deleted ASAP.

Comment: Isn't it a concept in [Material Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design), e.g., with mobile apps or Angular (not a rhetorical question)?